# My syntax files don't contain @Spell declarations

Tags: vim, spell-check

Apparently spell checking is something that should come by default in vim. However, many (the majority actually - 154 with spell declarations vs 397 without) of the shipped syntax files don't appear to contain @Spell declarations. For example, in C++ if spell is set *everything* is spell checked, rather than just comments which would be somewhat reasonable.

(C++ is the one I care about the most at the moment, though there are others that I'd like to have spelling for, like for instance Haskell).

Am I missing something? Are there versions of the standard syntax files that do contain those spell declarations?

vim --version:

```
Huge version with GTK2 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_binary
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static
+balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white
+browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     -tcl
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+cindent         +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
+clientserver    -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
+clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      +toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +insert_expand   -perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python          +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con_gui  -lua             +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            +ruby            +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      +X11
+dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     +xim
+emacs_tags      +mouseshape      -sniff           +xsmp_interact
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     +xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        -mouse_gpm       +statusline      -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   -sun_workshop    
+farsi           +mouse_netterm   +syntax          
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12   -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: gcc   -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic  -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim   -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0   -lSM -lICE -lXpm -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE  -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux  -ldl    -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions   -lruby-1.9.1 -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm  -L/usr/lib
```

Comment: My cpp.vim was last modified in 2012 Jun 14. It brings in the c.vim syntax file which does contain @Spell declarations.  What version of Vim are you using, including patchlevel? (`vim --version` on the command line)

Comment: @Heptite Vim 7.3, patchlevel 831. Pulled from hg and compiled it myself sometime this year, I've added the whole output of vim --version to the question. In any case, does your C++ syntax work then? I mean, do you only get spellchecking in comments?

Comment: That's odd. I would think you would have some spell checking support for C/C++; I also pull from Mercurial, although I'm up to patchlevel 918.  And yes, I only get spell highlighting in comments.

Comment: Checked the syntax directory from hg, seems to work now

Answer (score 5):

The latest source code and runtime files can be downloaded via FTP or retrieved from Mercurial; see [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/sources.php) for details.

My current version of `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/cpp.vim` is from `2002 Jul 15`, a time when Vim 6.1 was current. Indeed, many syntax files do not yet use the spell checking support introduced in Vim 7.0. The only way to fix this is to volunteer and add these definitions, and then send a patch to the original maintainer or start maintaining the file yourself.